# Extract rows from dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Extract rows from pandas based on a few conditions, for example:
Dataframe:

[image]

Conditions:

1. Where column a1 is not 'do' and all other columns are 'do':
   output:

[image]

2. Where column a1 & a2 is not 'do' and all other columns are 'do':

[image]

Basically we are iterating over columns one by one and extracting dataframe by combining the column index and before columns if there values is not 'do' and for the remaining columns value is 'do'.

Comment: 1- please provide your input as text for reproducibility, not images. 2- what is the exact output if you have more rows that match either condition?

Comment: @mozway This is an and condition not or. So, either will never occur.

Comment: So you only ever have **one** row for each condition?

Answer (score 1):

The exact logic is unclear, but you don't need to iterate, use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# conditions
m1 = df['a1'].ne('do')
m2 = df['a2'].ne('do')
m3 = df.drop(columns=['a1', 'a2']).eq('do').all(axis=1)

# a1 is not 'do' and all other columns are 'do'
out1 = df[m1 & (~m2) & m3]

# a1 & a2 is not 'do' and all other columns are 'do'
out2 = df[m1 & m2 & m3]
```

For a more dynamic approach, you can define the grouping columns:

```
cols = ['a1', 'a2']

group = df[cols].ne('do').mul(2**np.arange(len(cols))).sum(axis=1)

out_dfs = dict(list(df[df.drop(columns=cols).eq('do').all(axis=1)].groupby(group)))
```

The output will be a dictionary of dataframes, with the key being a binary encoded combination of the non-do columns.

Comment: I want a dynamic way, If i have 10 columns then there will be many condition, I don't want that

Comment: @sadaa then you need to much better explain what you want and to provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates a dynamic implementation that may be close to your needs. Please refine it further based on your specific use case.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Col1': ['OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'Not OK', 'OK'],
    'Col2': ['OK', 'Not OK', 'OK', 'Not OK', 'OK', 'Not OK'],
    'Col3': ['OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'Not OK', 'Not OK', 'OK'],
    'Col4': ['IS OK', 'OK', 'Not OK', 'Not OK', 'Not OK', 'OK'], 
    'Col5': ['Not OK', 'OK', '!=OK', 'Not OK', 'Not OK', 'Not OK'] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
masks = []
for col in df.columns:
    if col in ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']:
        masks.append(df[col] == 'OK')
    elif col in ['Col4', 'Col5']:
        masks.append(df[col] != 'OK')
combined_mask = masks[0]
for mask in masks[1:]:
    combined_mask = combined_mask & mask
print(df[combined_mask])
```

**Output**

the first 3 columns are 'OK', the last 2 columns are NOT 'OK'

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3    Col4    Col5                                                                    
0   OK   OK   OK   IS OK  Not OK                                                                    
2   OK   OK   OK  Not OK    !=OK
```